# Syntax error near unexpected token 'iptables'

Tags: shell

I have this error in a script `iptable`.

```
./iptables-firewall.sh line 4: syntax error near unexpected token 'iptables'

./iptables-firewall.sh line 4: iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s $SERVER_IP --sport 1024:65535 -d $ip --dport 53 -m state -- state NEW, ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

On this code:

```
SERVER_IP="ppp"
DNS_SERVER="8.8.8.8"
for ip in $DNS_SERVER do
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s $SERVER_IP --sport 1024:65535 -d $ip --dport 53 -m state -- state NEW, ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -d $SERVER_IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
done
```

Comment: Remove the space between inside `-- state`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do` in `for` loop must be on a line of it's own.

shell can't guess if it is a keyword or an argument named do.

just write

```
SERVER_IP="ppp"
DNS_SERVER="8.8.8.8"
for ip in $DNS_SERVER 
do
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s $SERVER_IP --sport 1024:65535 -d $ip --dport 53 -m state -- state NEW, ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -d $SERVER_IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
done
```

an alternative is to end the statement with a semicolon

```
for id in $DNS_SERVER ; do
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a semicolon after `$DNS_SERVER` and before `do`.